# Cannot read data from an xlsx file in RStudio

Tags: r, excel, perl, xlsx

I have installed the required packages - `gdata` and `ggplot2` and I have installed `perl`.

```
library(gdata)
library(ggplot2)

# Read the data from the excel spreadsheet
df = data.frame(read.xls ("AssignmentData.xlsx", sheet = "Data", header = TRUE, perl = "C:\\Strawberry\\perl\\bin\\perl.exe"))
```

However when I run this I get the following error:

```
Error in xls2sep(xls, sheet, verbose = verbose, ..., method = method,  : 
  Intermediate file 'C:\Users\CLAIRE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpE3UYWA\file8983d8e1efc.csv' missing!
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\STRAWB~1\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:/Users/Claire1992/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/gdata/perl/xls2csv.pl"  "AssignmentData.xlsx" "C:\Users\CLAIRE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpE3UYWA\file8983d8e1efc.csv" "Data"' had status 2 
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument
```

Comment: "AssignmentData.xlsx" is not found... see `list.files()` if it do not show "AssignmentData.xlsx" you have set the wrongt path, see `getwd()` and use ?setwd to set it correct

Comment: How do I set it to correct path? @ckluss

Comment: Well, e.g. try replacing `AssignmentData.xlsx` by the full path to `AssignmentData.xlsx`, e.g. `c:/Users/userC22/AssignmentData.xlsx` or `~/AssignmentData.xlsx` - whatever it is on your computer.

Comment: Alternatively, you could run the command `setwd("directory, where the file is situated")` before running your code. Then, R will search for files in that directory. You can easily check that you have set the correct directory using `list.files()` as was already mentioned by ckluss.

Comment: Yes @Stibu that was the solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Stibu I realised I had to set my work directory. This is the command you use to run in Rstudio; setwd("C/Documents..."). The file path is where the excel file is located.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue but I solved it differently. 
My problem was because my file was saved as Excel (extension .xls) but it was a txt file.
I corrected the file and I did not meet any other error with the R function.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer to this question.